Error bar and marker location on Seaborn lmplot using x_estimator
I want to make a lmplot with Seaborn showing the mean of my data including the standard deviation. However, the error bars are not located in the middle of the marker. Does anyone know if you can change the location of either the error bar or marker in seaborn or any other suggestions? It seems that the marker location changes when I am customizing the marker type markers = "$\circ$". Please find the script and plot below:
sns.lmplot(
    data=df1,
    x="Filtration_time",
    y="Resistance_filt 10^12",
    hue="Dia_media",
    legend=None,
    x_estimator=np.mean,
    x_bins=5,
    x_ci="sd",
    markers="$\circ$",
    palette=["black", "slategrey"],
    fit_reg=False,
    scatter_kws={"s": 150, "linewidths": 0.1, "edgecolor": "k"},
).set(xlabel="Filtration time [min]", ylim=(0, 12), xlim=(0, 60))



I tried to reproduce this issue with Seaborn 0.13.2 and matplotlib 3.8.3 with PyCharm on Windows, and to me the circles look nicely centered on the lines.  Which environment are you using? Or are you saving to e.g. a pdf file format?
